# How to access a node server located on a virtual machine from the host pc?

Tags: windows, virtual-machines

I have a simple node server running in a Virtual machine , using windows server 2012 .

I want to access the server from my host pc which has Windows 10 pro OS.

I can access the server from the guest pc by using :

```
http://localhost:8081/customer
```

in the browser.

I have tried to find the IP address of the VM by using the `ipconfig` and `arp` commands but the IP address i got doesn't work (can t get a response)

I have tried specifying inbound and outgoing rules for the specific port in the Windows Server Firewall but the result was the same .

Finally i switched the firewall OFF but i still can't get a result . I m a newbie on servers and networks so I m sure i miss something

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you have to check is, what your Network Adapter Settings of your virtual machine are.

If they are configured as NAT at will get a little more complicated. 
You can set it on Bridge mode. Bridge mode will act, as the VM is connected directly to your Network. This will only work, if you have access to a network on your host.

Because images explain more than words:

[Here is the picture which explains everything very good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLpgx.png)

If you are running in NAT mode, you have to do Port forwarding. I would suggest you, to use Bridge mode because it is easier.

If you don't know, you can find out the ip via cmd `ipconfig`

Comment: Also, which tool are you using? VMWare or Virtualbox or something else?